# Не работает геокодер в приложении

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Всем привет! Я использую Яндекс геокодер в приложении cordova.
Карты работают нормально, однако геокодер выдает ошибку:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 429 (Too Many Requests)

Я узнал что это из-за лимитов, однако  я их никак не мог израсходовать, в Кабинете разработчика видна нагрузка: Израсходовано 0

Возможно это связанно с тем что у приложения нет явного домена сайта, а так же приложение не передает заголовок Referer.

Мое приложение отдает заголовок: X-Requested-With: [имя пакета приложения]

Я включит ключ для MapKit – мобильный SDK, поставил его как `script.src = "https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&amp;apikey=[мой ключ]`
В итоге тоже самое.
Что мне делать?

Comment: `Возможно это связанно с тем что у приложения нет явного домена сайта, а так же приложение не передает заголовок Referer.` - API уже полгода не работает без ключа, причина ошибок именно в этом.

Comment: Ключ я указал, без ключа появляются другие ошибки. Я разобрался, дело в том что яндекс запрещает динамически загружать скрипты со своего сервера.

Answer (score 0):

Когда вы получаете ключ в Кабинете разработчика Яндекса, вы получаете его для какого-либо продукта. Если просто вставить ключ от MapKit в подключение JavaScript API, это не будет работать.

Подключите к своему ключу продукт "JavaScript API и HTTP API Геокодера" и всё будет ОК.